# "Argument of \OT1\" has an extra }" when I have an umlaut in the name

Tags: bibtex, mactex

I'm trying to compile the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ab_cd_2015,
  author = {{N{\"o}me}, Name},
  year         = {2014},
  title        = "Why Is Apple Launching a New Version of the {{iPod}}?"
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Random citation \cite{ab_cd_2015} embeddeed in text.

 % acm, plain works
 % alpha, alphadin, alphaurl, geralpha work not
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

When I compile this, I get:

```
(./mwe.aux) (./mwe.bbl
! Argument of \OT1\" has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{{N{\"}}14}
```

When I change `author` to either `{N{\"o}me, Name}`, `{{N{o}me}, Name}` or `{N\"ome, Name}` it compiles fine. What is it about `{{N{\"o}me}, Name}` that triggers the error? I generate the BibTeX from Zotero, and I'm trying to come up with rules that generate working BibTeX, this one has me stumped.

Comment: Sorry, but Zotero is known for handing malformed bib entries. In particular, `author={{N{\"o}me}, Name}` is absurd.

Comment: You can't pin this on Zotero -- this is my own doing. I'm trying to reduce the absurdity to the minimum, but it's not just bracing: `author = {nN\"ome, Name}` *also* flames out.

Comment: `N\"ome` is wrong anyway.

Comment: OK, learn something new everyday. I don't generate that, but I always though `\"` meant "put umlauts on next char". Thanks, that clears that up for me.

Comment: It's wrong in a BibTeX author field, where it must be `N{\"o}me`

Comment: `author = {{van G{\"o}gh}, Vincent}` does compile, where `author = {{N{\"o}me}, Name}` does not. Any idea what's the relevant difference between the two?

Comment: The number of letters: the new one writes `\bibitem[{van}14]{b}`, so it skips the problem

Comment: Is there a good source I could use to start understanding this process?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34705/discussion-between-retorquere-and-egreg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field

```
author = {{N{\"o}me}, Name},
```

is malformed, according to the (complex) rules of BibTeX, because it produces the faulty entry

```
\bibitem[{N{\"}}14]{ab_cd_2015}
```

in the `.bbl` file.

Essentially, the inner braces are ignored, so you end up as if the name was

```
N\"ome
```

which would produce almost the same, that is,

```
\bibitem[N\"14]{ab_cd_2015}
```

The only difference are the missing braces.

With

```
author = {N{\"o}me, Name},
```

you get the correct

```
\bibitem[N{\"o}m14]{ab_cd_2015}
```

Note that the number of letters is as expected, that is, three. Also in the previous cases there are three tokens, but not the ones LaTeX expects.

Comment: OK, that gets me closer to understanding what's going on. I've seen that `14` crop up, but I can't trace back why it does. So the best approach would then be to not wrap braces around the last name, as a general rule?

Comment: For some reason, adding `\relax ` after the opening brace allows all the failing samples I could throw at it so far to compile. Is this safe to do? I'm stuck with the task of translating "whatever is in Zotero" to "BibTeX that compiles always" algorithmically.

Comment: I had been adding braces around the last name to account for things like particles, such as described here: http://nwalsh.com/tex/texhelp/bibtx-23.html

Comment: I have a very similar case. Hovever, the author surname contains of two parts, namely {D{\'i}az Alonso}, Javier, i.e. the braces are necessary. What do I do in such a case?